# Take desktop screenshots in a Jenkins Build Slave during Selenium Tests

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have some problem with Jenkins and Selenium. 
I have a Jenkins Master and some Build Slaves, installed as Windows Services on Windows Server 2016 machines, in which I perform build jobs. In some of these jobs, I perform test with Selenium and I need to take some screenshots of these tests, but all the screenshots that I got are black. 
Reading on the web, I found that many people are facing this kind issue. But I also found this, https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/interact-with-desktop/, in which is reported that it's not allowed for Windows Services to interact with desktop. 
So, the question is: it's possible to make interact Jenkins Slave Service with the desktop in order to take some screenshot of it?

Comment: I suggest to uninstall Jenkins slave service and launch slave from task scheduler, in user context instead. This way they can interact with desktop.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your comment!!!
I was thinking to link Jenkins Master and Slave through SSH. In this way, I will not have any Windows Service and the Executor should be able to interact with desktop.
I will update you.